# Bootstrap 5 alternative way to make border responsive

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

So I want to achieve a responsive border with the help of bootstrap5 where certain breakpoint will make border not shown

my ideas was something like code below

`<p class="border-bottom border-lg-0-bottom border-lg-end">text here</p>`

but this code would not would not work, any help?

Comment: @CyrusKabir tried searching for different keyword before, probably why I didn't find it back then

Comment: @Yogi that's the first time i read it. i guess i should try but i never used scss nor API of it

Comment: @kp1304 it's ok you can create your own utility classes like (.border-sm, ...) in style.css and media queries. scss make it easier and more maintainable for generating classes for that purpose if you are new to css it's better you create your own classes for borders and apply them base on device size with media queries.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in html and classnames.

You can use sass instead:

```
.border-lg-0-bottom {       
   @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) { 
       border-bottom: 0;
   }
}
```

You can use css. Add this to your `<head>` tag or you can use css file if you know how to:

```
<style>
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
    .border-lg-0-bottom {       
        border-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: i must then use scss then? i havent learnt that, and i use cdn instead of installing the bootstrap

Comment: ok I'll update the answer to css to be easy for you. If it worked please accept the answer. I appreciate that.

Comment: sorry it seems like the border from bootstrap is still active even with this code

Comment: Ensure you tag has class `border-lg-0-bottom` and try my updated answer again